# Do each(), text(), or any of the selectors I'm using have any compatibility issue with IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a quite extent code, so I'm gonna post the chuck that matters, and try to explain what's going on. I found the exact piece which is disabling my whole jQuery for IE. I read many posts and checked about problems like the use of old libraries, sets of IE, but I couldn't find an answer.

This code runs smoothly and achieves the result: every time an input is made for any input of type number, it fires an alert.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("input[type=number]").on('input', function(){
      alert("123")
    });
 });
```

Since the selector is working (tested in the previous example), after inputting any of the fields, I try to sum up all the number inputs from my form and text the result. Then, it's blocking my whole code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("input[type=number]").on('input', function(){
     let tot = 0;
     $("form#form-residential :input[type='number']").each((i, el) => tot += parseInt(el.value || 0, 10));
     $('.total-residential').text(tot);
     });
  });
```

Has anyone ever experienced something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

The arrow function, which is unsupported in every version of IE according to MDN, is causing the error.

You could replace it with an anonymous function declaration `function(i, el){ tot += parseInt(el.value || 0, 10); }`

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help]. This is an **often**-repeated duplicate question. On SO, instead of posting new answers, which just clutters things up and leads to a mess of different (sometimes contractory) answers in lots of different places, we close duplicates and point to the original question that it duplicates.

Comment: Would be the solution something like this? 

`$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("input[type=number]").on('input', function(){
     let tot = 0;
  var x = function(i, el){ tot += parseInt(el.value || 0, 10); }
     $("form#form-residential :input[type='number']").each(x);
     $('.total-residential').text(tot);
     });
  });`

Comment: Working! Amazing @Holden Rohrer